# Flask: why image transfers so slow?

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a simple Flask app that will return the most up to date image from a video source. The video source is running on a thread. The Flask appp is deployed with gevent. The client makes a GET request every 5 seconds (it's currently 5 seconds, because the image transfers are slow). The images are between 50 and 60 KB and usually take between 3 to 5 seconds to transfer. This is a local network, so I'd expect the speed to be much greater. Is there some optimization I should be aware of?

As a side note, I've also used Flask-SocketIO websockets and have the same problem with transfer speed.

The app code:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template
import threading
from cStringIO import StringIO

app = Flask(__name__)

img = StringIO()

def save_video():
    global img
    jpg_frame = some_image_source()
    img.reset()
    img.write(jpg_frame)
    img.truncate()


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/image<rand_num>')
def get_image(rand_num):
    global img
    new_img = StringIO(img.getvalue())
    return send_file(new_img, mimetype='image/jpg')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    imgthread = threading.Thread(target=save_video)
    imgthread.daemon = True
    imgthread.start()
    http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 9090), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

I send requests with random numbers so that the browser doesn't fetch a cached image. The client code I have in the HTML body (head only has title):

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
        myImageElement.src = '/image' + Math.random();
    }, 5000);
</script>
<img src="/image0" id="myImage" />
```

Comment: Ever found a solution for this one?

Comment: Don't remember - sorry. If you find the answer, publish it here and I'll mark it.